# Linq Exception on cast

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I have a small piece of code to refactor. Someone wrote cast in such style:

```
list.OrderBy(u => (int)u.Original).First();
```

Sometimes this code throw Invalid Cast Exceptions (field `Original` is of type `object`).

Example:

```
list[0].Orginal = 200,
list[1].Orginal = 85
```

Everything is Ok.

```
list[0].Orginal = 275452,
list[1].Orginal = 154754
```

Throws Exception

Anyone know why?

Comment: Why is `Original` of type `object` in the first place? Thats probably where you should be refactoring

Comment: Why do you need the use of cast?

Comment: Also, except for the typo's in the examples, I can't see how those could throw an exception, you should try to create an [mcve].

Comment: Your `u.Original` might not be an `int`.

Comment: Try FirstOrDefault() because there may be a case that the sequence is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it sometimes throws the invalid cast exception, it means you sometimes have `non-int` types of instances in your list. You can avoid them before casting, but this is not really a good type of a design I guess.

I would do as I show below as a quick fix.

```
list.Where(u => u.Original is int).OrderBy(u => (int)u.Original).First();
```

Then I would go ahead and check what am I missing as following:

```
list.Where(u => !(u.Original is int)).ForEach(u => Console.WriteLine(u.Original.GetType()))
```

Then fix the `list` beforehand.

Comment: I check DB schema (this list is from DB Procedure) and someone change int to bigint and doesn't change this code. Thanks a lot for targeting to answer.

Comment: If now you can use big ints the database, you should consider using longs in your code instead.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested you should avoid the unnecessary cast. In your class simply change the type of `Orginal` from `object` to `int` and you won't need the cast in the LINQ query.

Comment: But in order to get an invalid cast, something must not be an integer.

Comment: What if the list is only a filtered version of another list which really holds `object` - different types of instances?

Comment: You're right, and I can't see either where his code may throw that exception...

Answer (score -2):

The code compiles and runs with no problem.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/dadrYJ

## These are not the Datatypes you are looking for

What you actually meant was

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ygJTyU

```
list[0].Orginal = 2147483647;
list[1].Orginal = 154754;
```

where n > 0

Given that. The bug is pretty clear.

Refactor:

```
var value = int.MaxValue + n;
list[0].Orginal = value;
```

Refactor:

```
int64 value = int.MaxValue + n;
list[0].Orginal = value;
```

Therefore:

```
public int Lambda_OrderBy(Foo u)
{
   return (int) u.Orginal;
}
```

Refactor:

```
public int Lambda_OrderBy(Foo u)
{
   int64 value = u.Orginal;
   return (int) value; // FAIL!
}
```